# Overlaying subplot on seaborn factorplot

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm creating a plot with [factorplot](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.factorplot.html?highlight=factorplot#seaborn.factorplot) and then trying to add a subplot on top of each box.  How can I get the x-axis locations of each individual box in the factor plot to put another line on top?

Maybe there's a way to get all the x-axis values of each box plot on the axes?

Here's my basic factor plot:

[image]

I want to add 1 subplot (the circle) in the middle of each box plot.  However, I cannot figure out how to get the x-value of each box to properly space the points.

I see a lot of code for positions and offsets in the seaborn source that lays these out.  However, I'm wondering if there is a more straight-forward method to get this information or at least approximate it.

Comment: What are you trying to show with the plot on top of the boxes? Depending on what you want to do it might be easier to use one of the other seaborn categorical functions, which will draw things properly with respect to the boxes automatically.

Comment: I have a bunch of data points and I'm trying to draw the distribution of those points as a whole with the box plots. Then, showing where in that distribution several 'important' data points lie for emphasis.

Comment: It looks like using stripplot might work, but I only want to show a select for data points, not all of them.  However, I'm not using version .6 yet because I'll need to update quite a bit of other code to properly upgrade.

Comment: Yeah I would recommend `stripplot` but I guess in the meantime you could figure out which lines in the `ax.lines` list correspond to the vertical whiskers and then use the `xydata` of those lines to position the points.

Comment: Alternatively, the positions are predictable. The boxes are centered on 0-based integer values and the offsets for the hue nesting are computed with this code: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/categorical.py#L349

Comment: Excellent. Thanks so much for the help.  I'll definitely be upgrading in the near future and using `stripplot` or the `hue_offsets` you mentioned. However, for now any ideas on the best way to identify the whisker lines from all the lines on the plot?

Comment: They're drawn in a predictable order I just forget off the top of my head what it is. Should be easy to figure out though (the two x values will be the same).

Comment: Good idea. Thanks again! Looking forward to the upgrades in the new seaborn!

Answer (score 0):

As per @mwaskom's comments, you can use `sns.stripplot()` (and now also `sns.swarmplot()`) to include your data points with a data summary plot such as a box or violinplot.